# dynamic work allocation for threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm wanting to know how I would set up a class that would dynamically allocate work for threads, preferably in C#.  I've looked at [[this]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) for the ray tracer explanation, but I don't even see a description of how this would look.  I don't want something overly complicated.

I have a group of tasks that are too large to just split evenly and give out to my threads.  I want to dynamically allocate small portions of the tasks to each thread, and then when the threads finish, obtain their results and give them more tasks.  I know I did something like this years ago, but I can't find those notes nor have I been successful with Google or here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

below is my idea of what it would look like in pseudo code.  It's not going to look pretty but just to give you an idea of what i'm talking about.

```
TaskList = ArrayList of n tasks
ResultList = ArrayList of thread results
create x threads
integer TasksCompleted
while(TasksCompleted < TaskList.size){
  thread = next available thread in pool
  ResultList.add(thread.results)
  tasksCompleted += thread.numOfTasks
  thread.doWork(Next set of Tasks)
}
clean up threads
processResults(ResultList)
```

Comment: You should look at [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) or if you can use .Net 4.5 maybe look at [DataFlow Pipelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx)

Comment: You should also look at [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx), which was designed for this precise scenario.

Comment: What you are describing is a thread pool.  C# has had a thread pool since version 2.0, although it has expanded on it's functionality dramatically in version 4.0 by adding the TPL and other higher level parallel programming tools built on top of the thread pool.  Be sure that these can't do what you need before writing your own thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.0+ then you can use the Parallel.For method. It launches as many threads as it sees necessary to parallel process the loops. The nice thing is that it manages the threads and monitors them for you. Here's a how-to introduction to the parallel for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

You should also look into other constructs that the task parallel library introduced in .NET 4.0. It has a lot of really neat multi-threading helpers that make multi-threading a lot easier than launching and managing your own threads. You can see the MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) to manage a simple work queue.

When a worker thread has finished with it's current item, it will remove a new item from the work queue, process that item, then add it to the output queue.

A separate consumer thread removes completed items from the output queue and does something with them.

At the end we must wait for all the workers to finish (`Task.WaitAll(workers)`) before we can mark the output queue as completed (`outputQueue.CompleteAdding()`).

This example just has ints for the work items; in real code, you would use objects which encapsulated the work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }

        void run()
        {
            int threadCount = 4;
            Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

            Task.Factory.StartNew(consumer);

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            {
                int workerId = i;
                Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
                workers[i] = task;
                task.Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
                inputQueue.Add(i);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
            inputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Task.WaitAll(workers);
            outputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void worker(int workerId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

            foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
                outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
        }

        void consumer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is starting.");

            foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is finished.");
        }

        BlockingCollection<int> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        BlockingCollection<int> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    }
}
```

---

**Plinq and Dataflow**

[You should also look into Plinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx), and - if you can use .Net 4.5 - also [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx)